# How can we pass a List and a separate String using @RequestBody in SpringBoot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, http, spring-mvc

I have written this code but getting  Status: 400 Bad Request error in `JSON`

```
@CrossOrigin
    @PostMapping(value = "/retail/scorecard/addKPI", consumes = {MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE})
public @ResponseBody Object addKpi(@Valid @RequestParam List<KPIReq> kpiReqList,@RequestParam("goalId") String goalId,
        HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res) throws RecordNotFoundException, Exception {
```

Comment: Can you add Your request and error log?

Comment: add your json request, if you are posting any query it must be more sufficient to answer.

Answer (score 1):

Use `@Valid @RequestBody List<KPIReq> kpiReqList` for your list. May be an error in your json.

Answer (score 1):

The Request param essentially maps parts of the request uri to an object. Like for uri:

```
http://localhost/api/v1/search?type=11&type=12&color=RED&color=GREY
```

you could map it like :

```
        public @Responsebody Object addKpi(
        @RequestParam(value="type", required=false) List<String> types,
        @RequestParam(value="color", required=false) List<String> colors)
        {
            ....
        }
```

Instead of passing the List as a **RequestParam** , why don't you try providing it as part of the request body. Complex objects are better to be send as request body.Like:

```
    @CrossOrigin
    @PostMapping(value = "/retail/scorecard/addKPI", consumes = {MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE})
    public @ResponseBody Object addKpi(@Valid @RequestBody List<KPIReq> kpiReqList,@RequestParam("goalId") String goalId,
            HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res) throws RecordNotFoundException, Exception {
```

Answer (score 0):

Your error is 400 bad request that's mean your function with an object with type X but don't receive it, Can you try to add the name for you

```
 @RequestParam(name = "kpiReqList")  
 @RequestParam(name ="goalId")
```

which the type of the list and the id Json or XML?